# Twilio web app notify

Tags: web-applications, push, twilio, xojo

I need push notification on mobile webapp (Xojo, iOS+Android), I was thinking to use Twilio Notify Beta but it is not clear to me how it works.

Say a user starts the webapp: first time it should bind with a REST api, but I don't understand where to find the "device token", how to define if the mobile user has to accept the notification or he/she has already did it, etc.

Docs are [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/bindings).

Can you push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You've found yourself among the wrong part of the documentation there I'm afraid.

The section you want is the [Notify Usage](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify) section which gives you an introduction and then leads on to:

- [Registering for notifications on iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/guides/register-for-notifications-ios)
- [Registering for notifications on Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/guides/register-for-notifications-android)

Both articles walk you through how to get a device token, register a binding and send a push notification.

If you are looking to do this for the web too, Twilio Notify supports sending notifications via FCM. You need to require [FCM's JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) and use that to get a "registration token" which you can also set up as a binding (by following the rest of the Android guide once you have the registration token).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: That's clearer now. In the guide there is a
`client.notify` that gives a "no attribute notify for Client".

Comment: Oh, because Notify is a beta product you need to install the alpha version of the library. I don't know which language you're using, but take a look on the library page for instructions for installing the alpha version.

Comment: Argh, the alpha! Completely forgot about it. Looks like it works, thank you so much.